# few indeed, yet too many

Tags: phrase-meaning

Other objects of vengeance, **few indeed, yet too many**, were found among the republican chiefs.

The highlighted part, isn't it a nonsense? **Few** and **many** both seem to modify **objects**, I guess. The objects are few, but too many?

Please help me.

Comment: Not a nonsense, **yet** contrast.

Comment: There were few, yet too many, turds at the picnic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a contrast for effect. It suggests that their are **few** other object of vengeance - that the number of such was small - but that even that small number is **too many**.

Saying that something is both **few** and **many** would be a contradiction (though not necessarily nonsense - not all contradictions are nonsensical), but this is not *many*. It is **too many**, which is to say the number is larger than someone judges good. Think of it in similar terms to "**only one** civilian was killed in the attack, but one is **too many**".

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your kind explanation.